# proof by contradiction with the well ordering property

Tags: proof-explanation

I am having trouble understanding this proof that every integer from 2 onwards can expressed as a product of primes:

Assume the negation of the statement is true (proof by contradiction):

Negation of the statement: There exists an integer greater or equal to 2 that cannot be expressed as a product of primes.

Let S be the set of integers from 2 onwards which cannot be expressed as a product of primes.

By the well ordering property, this set has a least element s, say.

The proof then goes on to show that s is a product of numbers less than s which are prime. So s is a product of primes and I accept this.

The proof then states "So we have a contradiction and s is not in S therefore S is empty."

So the proof shows that s is not an element of S.

How does this prove that S is empty? Do we not have to show that the next least elements (i.e. s+1, s+2 etc) are not in S?

Thank you

Comment: Your negation of the original statement is wrong and should read "*there exists* an integer greater or equal to 2 that cannot be expressed as a product of primes".

Comment: I corrected the negation of the original statement and I understand that we don't need the well ordering property here. I was trying to understand how the well ordering property is used though.

Comment: It's used to obtain a contradiction, and that's all we need to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of what we want to prove should read "*there exists* an integer greater or equal to 2 that cannot be expressed as a product of primes". This is equivalent to the statement that your set $S$ is non-empty. Therefore, upon arriving at a contradiction, this statement has to be false, i.e., $S$ has to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

We have shown the least value of the set does not belong to the set without actually looking at what the value is. So in short a set cannot exist, as no matter what set we create it will have a least value and as we have shown that cannot exist so the set has to be a null set.

In other words consider $S$ now you have said the least value does not belong to the set. Remove that value and create a new set $S_{new}=S-s$ and you can take the new set into consideration and continue removing elements till there are none left